# WordPress: Can't get title to not display on home page

Tags: php, wordpress

This should be so simple, but in this case, it isn't. In the templates/content-page.php of my theme I want the title to display on all pages, except one... the homepage. I have tried various versions of this code, but nothing works.

```
<?php if ( !is_front_page() || !is_home() ) { ?>
    <header class="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I am assuming the static page is set correctly in **Settings->Reading->Your homepage displays ->"A static page"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we don't need to put the echo with the the_title() function. It will echo automatically.

```
if ( !is_front_page() && is_home() ) {

    // Default homepage ( both the front page and the recent posts page){

   <header class="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>

}
```

Comment: This was a bit too much. I simplified it to this and it did work. Thanks.

<?php if ( !is_front_page() && !is_home() ) { ?>
 <header class="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>
 <?php } ?>

Comment: Yep, the frequent "AND/OR" confusion strikes again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do this? I have in my page.php file

```
<?php get_header();
$p = get_post();
?>
<div id="main">
   <div id="content">
      <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
         <h1 class='pageTitle'><?php the_title();?></h1>
         <p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
         <hr>
      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
   </div>
   <?php get_sidebar('Right Sidebar');?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, I do. Because I don't want the title to appear on the homepage and I do want it to appear on every other page.